# Highcharts creates same text 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, bar-chart

I was using Highcharts 1.7 and everything was working just fine with this label that gets repeated (the one in the left, the 0.025), but in the actual highcharts version, which I need, the label gets rendered 3 times. Not sure what is going wrong here.
So basically> 
Highcharts repeats the 0.25 text multiple times. 
Refer to this link for the code and working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/pCuUW/

```
$(function() {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        'chart': {
            'renderTo': 'container',
            'type': 'bar',
            'width': 500,
            'height': 150
        },
        'exporting': {
            'enabled': false
        },
        'yAxis': {
            'max': 1400,
            'title': {
                'text': ''
            }
        },
        'title': {
            'text': 'My normal barchart'
        },
        'plotOptions': {
            'bar': {
                'pointWidth': 30,
                'borderWidth': 0,
                'dataLabels': {
                    'enabled': true,
                    'distance': -10,
                    'color': 'black',
                    'padding': 5,
                    'x': -45,
                    'backgroundColor': '#ffffff',
                    'borderWidth': 1,
                    'borderColor': '#000000',                       
                    'style': {
                        'fontSize': '12px',
                        'font-weight': 'bold'
                    },

                }
            }
        },
        'credits': {
            'enabled': false
        },
        'labels': {
            'enabled': false
        },
        'legend': {
            'enabled': false
        },
        'series': [{
            'data': [637]}]
    });
});

});
```

What is going wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Seems like a bug. You should probably contact the developer. It only seems to happen when you have only one item in the `data:` Array. It clears up when you have more: `'data': [637,123]`

Comment: aparently it was because i wasn't using a category text. It is certainly something that needs to be fixed tho, I will notify them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most probably because you have not mentioned an category  in **the x-axis**.

Try adding this

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Cost'], // just a default value
    title: {
        text: null
    }
},​
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pCuUW/1/)

Comment: @Romina12345 .. Glad to have helped :)